# How to launch a program from bash script, then close Terminal but keep the program alive

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I wanted to have an icon in my desktop to start [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) with a custom parameter which is read from the command line upon launching.

This is what I came up with:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
default_temperature=4500
echo "Default color temperature (Night) is "$default_temperature"K."
read -p "Type in the desired value: " temperature
temperature=${temperature:-$default_temperature}
nohup redshift-gtk -l "-23.9141:-147.6650" -t "6500:"$temperature &
```

The above file is saved as `/home/redshift.sh`. I also created a desktop entry to launch it, with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Redshift (script)
Comment=Custom script to start Redshift with color temperature input
Exec="/home/redshift.sh"
Icon=redshift
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

(the first line was added automatically).

The expected behaviour is:

1. User double-clicks the desktop entry
2. Console opens and asks for (optional) input
3. Upon user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the script should launch the application named `redshift-gtk` (which is actually a Python script located at `/usr/bin`), with the specified arguments.

For now I don't care about checking whether the input is valid, nor if the process is already running.

An example of the (working) command would be:

```sh
redshift-gtk -l "-23.9141:-147.6650" -t "5500:2400"
```

And for the moment, I even simplified the launch script to simply this

```sh
nohup redshift-gtk -l "-23.9141:-147.6650" -t "5500:2400" &
```

And even tried

```sh
nohup redshift-gtk -l "-23.9141:-147.6650" -t "5500:2400" && exit
```

But none of these closes the Terminal window, it will just keep remain open. If I close it manually, the Redshift process is killed (and this is obviosly not desired).

Tried a number of possible solutions found online, none seems to work. Didn't find anything relevant here in SO.

Just how to do it properly?

Thanks

Comment: does '(command)& exit' not work?

Comment: @rosh sadly, no.

Comment: You should run the script in a screen session...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would recommend doing this would be via `screen`. It allows you to start processes from a virtual terminal, then detach from it, exit Terminal and then come back later and reattach to it (if the session still exists). For example:

```
screen -d -m redshift-gtk -l "-23.9141:-147.6650" -t "5500:2400"
```

Would launch the command in "detached mode" and then you could exit Terminal. If you wanted to check on the session when returning to Terminal you could do:

```
screen -list
```

Typical output looks something like this:

```
There is a screen on:
    58643..System(Detached)
1 Socket in /var/folders/qg/jxb2db8d2_57nrtq5vs0xcfw0000gn/T/.screen.
```

Check the man page for `screen` — lots of helpful info there.

Comment: Been trying this for the last hour or so. It consistently works both when called from the Terminal (i.e. `./redshift.sh`) and when clicking "Run" in the dialog after double-clicking the script file. But its behavior is erratic when launched by the desktop entry or when clicking "Run in Terminal" after double clicking. In the last case, it sometimes works promptly; sometimes it works the second time; but most often it'll take 5-8 attempts until launching `Redshift` appropriately. Very weird. Tried logging out and even restarting the system. I run Cinnamon 3.4.1 and gnome-terminal. Any clues?

Comment: Hmmm... without seeing the actual behavior it's hard for me to say what might be causing it. There are a couple of things you could try, one might be to put the actual command in it's own script and have it launch that way; also putting in a small delay before and after the screen command might help perhaps (eg. sleep 1). If the screen hasn't detached already and the Terminal has already exited then that could be the reason.

Comment: This is working for now! Will do some more testing tomorrow. In the meantime, thank you.

Comment: I managed to get it working properly with `sleep 1` after the `screen` command. It was not needed to include *before* `screen`. Perhaps you want to include this in the answer itself? Also (and this is a parallel question), do you know why my attempt with `nohup` and `&` didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

*(This suggestion is moot, in view of OP's original question.)*

In `bash`, you can try:

```
redshift-gtk -l "-23.9141:-147.6650" -t "5500:2400" &
disown $!
```

Note that, at any rate, `&` is what you need for spawning the sub-process -- `&&` will wait for it to complete.

*EDIT:*

I must have been reading your description very carelessly (or missed an update, if there was one,) so I was not taking into consideration the requirement to do input before continuing in the background.  You can do some magic to this effect with a utility called [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/), but it's far from an easy ride.  I'd love to be able to give you some more pointers, but I myself have only scratched the surface of using it.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the `&&`. Gotta catch up with some reading on `bash`. I tried your suggestion, it works when invoking the script from the Terminal _and_ when I run the script by double-click and selecting "Run" - however it doesn't work at all when calling from the Desktop entry, nor when double-clicking the script and selecting "Run in Terminal". This is similar to what I observed with l'L'l 's answer, using `GNU Screen`; however in that case, it sporadically works, and this solution doesn't. (continues)

Comment: (cont) the exact same thing happens without the `disown $!` in the last line. I made sure to try exactly your code and nothing more. Additionally, when calling from the Terminal, it won't `exit`, not even after closing `Redshift-gtk` from the Tray myself. See this image: http://i.imgur.com/dVsq7P0.png This is what's left in this case

Comment: some more random (probably not so useful) info:  adding a new line with `sleep 1` before this makes it work, provided that I remove the ampersand at the end. But Terminal doesn't close, and if I close it, Redshift is killed.